# I'm getting an error when running make -f hello.py. It says " hello.py:1: *** missing separator. Stop. "

Tags: python, makefile

This is the code for the makefile and hello.py . I was reading similar questions to mine and I believe this is a problem with a tab somewhere but I'm unable to find it. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Command line output:

```
hello.py:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

```
PYTHON = python3
VIEWER = less

.PHONY: clean run view other_run

run :   hello.py
        $(PYTHON) hello.py

other_run :     hello.py
        chmod u+x hello.py
        ./hello.py

view :  hello.py
        - $(VIEWER) hello.py
```

```
print("Hello, World!\n")
```

Comment: Please update your question with the command line and the full output.

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated it

Comment: The `-f` option tells `make` what *Makefile* to use; `hello.py` isn't a Makefile.

Comment: Yes, please label each of the sections in the question with their filenames.

Comment: What useful thing do you expect the command you're running to accomplish?

Comment: `make` is useful for when you have files which depend on each other in a particular hierarchy. Your example does not seem to exhibit any of that; if your real-world use case isn't significantly more interesting than this, probably consider whether `make` is actually providing any value here. I'm all for using `make` for unconventional things but this doesn't look like a good fit for its feature set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make -f hello.py` will treat `hello.py` as a `Makefile` which is almost certainly not what you want

> ```
>        -f file, --file=file, --makefile=FILE
>            Use file as a makefile.
> ```

you probably want just `make hello.py`

Comment: `hello.py` isn't a target, and I'm not aware of a useful default rule for `.py` files.